# Using wxGTK without X

Tags: wxwidgets

We are trying to cross compile the wxGTK (2.8.12) to our ARMv5 embedded device. 
Since RAM space is limited to 64MB, we thought of not using X11.
So, we have built DirectFB and GTK+ (with gdktarget as directfb and without x).

Now, we are trying to build wxGTK with GTK+. But it seems like, it need X11 header files. Got following compiler errors:

```
./src/unix/utilsx11.cpp:31:22: warning: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
./src/unix/utilsx11.cpp:33:23: warning: X11/Xutil.h: No such file or directory
./src/unix/utilsx11.cpp:40:22: warning: gdk/gdkx.h: No such file or directory
./src/unix/utilsx11.cpp:44: error: ‘Atom’ does not name a typeenter code here
....
```

Is it possible to build wxGTK with GTK+ (directfb) but without X?

Thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

wxGTK requires GTK+ and, while GTK+ can use different backends, notably Wayland, it's unlikely to be available on your device.

You could try building wxDirectFB instead, but wxDFB is a very alpha-quality port which hasn't been in use since quite some time, so you should be ready to do some work on it yourself in order to implement the missing parts (there will definitely be at least some).

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimalist GNOME implementation based on the GTK+. It is based on the X11 and GTK+. It can be build using OpenEmbedded or probably downloaded as prebuilt WM.

Now looking at it I think you can try GNOME Embedded with wxGTK.